# How do I loop through a string read from a file against a fixed set of characters individually and if they match print the string in powershell

Tags: powershell, loops

I currently have a foreach loop, that gets content from a small dictionary file (only strings over 3 characters). I am looking to compare each character in the $line against my other characters, in this case "b" "i" "n" "g" "o" so that if all the characters in $line are in bingo, then it prints the  word. If not it loops to the next word.
So far I have:

```html
foreach($line in Get-Content Desktop/dict.txt | Sort-Object Length, { $_ })
```

The bit I can't get (not too familiar with powershell) is this:

```html
    if($line.length -gt 3){
        if( i in $line == 'b')
        if( i in $line == 'i')
        if( i in $line == 'n')
        if( i in $line == 'g')
        if( i in $line == 'o')
    write-output $line
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to match the exact word `bingo` or are you looking to match a line that has all the characters in `bingo` like `asdbingoasd`?

Comment: Hi - if the word "bin" was in the dictionary, it would print out. As would "bingo". As long as the words in the dictionary had only the characters b i n g o then it would be printed. Hope that helps to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking parts of both answers I was able to get the result I was after. As I am new to this, not sure how to thank @martin and @santiago for their work.

This was the code that was put together, which was pretty much taking the dictionary file and then rather than a fixed string size made it greater than 3:

```html
$dict = @(Get-Content Desktop/dict.txt | Sort-Object Length, { $_ })
$word = 'bingo'

$dict |
     Where-Object { $_.length -gt 2 } |
     ForEach-Object {
         $dictwordLetters = [System.Collections.Generic.List[char]]::new($_.ToCharArray())
         $word.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {
             $dictwordLetters.Remove($_) | Out-Null
         }
         if (-not $dictwordLetters.Count) {
             $_
         }
     }
```

Your assistance was greatly appreciated.

Comment: Happy you could solve your problem. A few improvements you could consider, `.ToCharArray()` can be called outside the loop so it's only processed once. `if (-not $dictwordLetters.Count){...}` can be simplified to `if (-not $dictwordLetters){...}` and lastly, if you're looking for performance, a classic `foreach` loop is a lot faster than `foreach-object` and `where-object` when filtering large collections :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, if you want to check if `$line` is *contained* in **bingo** you could use the `-match` for case insensitive and `-cmatch` for case sensitive operators. See [Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1).

For example:

```
PS /> 'bingo' -match 'ing'
True

PS /> 'bingo' -match 'bin'
True

PS /> 'bingo' -match 'ngo'
True
```

The code could look like this:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content Desktop/dict.txt | Sort-Object Length, { $_ })
{
    if($line.length -gt 3 -and 'bingo' -match $line)
    {
        $line
        # you can add break here to stop this loop if the word is found
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit

If you want to check if 3 or more characters in **bingo** (in any order) are contained in `$line`, there are many ways to do this, this is the approach I would take:

```
# Insert magic word here
$magicWord = 'bingo'.ToCharArray() -join '|'

foreach($line in Get-Content Desktop/dict.txt | Sort-Object Length, { $_ })
{
    # Remove [Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase if you want it to be Case Sensitive
    $check = [regex]::Matches($line,$magicWord,[Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase)

    # If 3 or more unique characters were matched
    if(($check.Value | Select-Object -Unique).count -ge 3)
    {
        'Line is: {0} || Characters Matched: {1}' -f $line,-join $check.Value 
    }
}
```

#### Demo

Given the following words:

```
$test = 'ngob','ibgo','gn','foo','var','boing','ingob','oubingo','asdBINGasdO!'
```

It would yield:

```
Line is: ngob || Characters Matched: ngob
Line is: ibgo || Characters Matched: ibgo
Line is: boing || Characters Matched: boing
Line is: ingob || Characters Matched: ingob
Line is: oubingo || Characters Matched: obingo
Line is: asdBINGasdO! || Characters Matched: BINGO
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not on a computer at the moment. I would need it to : 
PS /> 'bingo' -match 'onb' would this work as well?

Comment: @Kartibok it would not. So you're looking for ___if 3 or more characters in bingo in any order are contained in `$line`___ I think. Is that so?

Comment: That is correct. That would mean all words in the dictionary that contain only those letters in any order would be printed.

Comment: @Kartibok ok, I edited the code, I think that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Gents: Much appreciated what you guys have done. I think my explanation is probably not as good as it should be. 
It my dictionary was:
apple, brown, green, cake, bin, pear, big, milk, bio, bong, bodings, gibson
The code would return:
bin, big, bio, bong
Does that help to clarify?

Answer (score 2):

So you want to get back any words that are the same length and have the same characters no matter the order?

```
$dict = @(
    'bingo'
    'rambo'
    'big'
    'gobin'
    'bee'
    'ebe'
    'been'
    'ginbo'
)

$word = 'bingo'

$dict |
    Where-Object { $_.length -eq $word.Length } |
    ForEach-Object {
        $dictwordLetters = [System.Collections.Generic.List[char]]::new($_.ToCharArray())
        $word.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {
            $dictwordLetters.Remove($_) | Out-Null
        }
        if (-not $dictwordLetters.Count) {
            $_
        }
    }
```

The following will be the output

```
bingo
gobin
ginbo
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my two cents:

```
$dict = 'apple', 'brown', 'green', 'cake', 'bin', 'pear', 'big', 'milk', 'bio', 'bong', 'bingo', 'bodings', 'gibson'
# the search term as string
$term = 'bingo'
# merge the unique characters into a regex like '[bingo]+'
$chars = '[{0}]+' -f (($term.ToCharArray() | Select-Object -Unique) -join '')

# loop over the array (lines in the text file)
$dict | ForEach-Object {
    # get all matched characters, uniqify and join if there are more matches. 
    $found = (($_ | Select-String -Pattern $chars -AllMatches).Matches.Value | Select-Object -Unique ) -join '' | Where-Object { $_.Length -ge 3 }
    if ($found) { 
        # outputting an object better explains what is matched in which line
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Line              = $_
            CharactersMatched = $found
        }
        # of course, you can also simply output the found matching characters
        # $found
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Line    CharactersMatched
----    -----------------
brown   bon              
bin     bin              
big     big              
bio     bio              
bong    bong             
bingo   bingo            
bodings boing            
gibson  gibon
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers all seem overly complicated. If you are trying to match strings then that sounds like a problem that requires a regular expression, and if that is the case then `Select-String` would be a better option than `Get-Content`. Below is an example, I am not sure if it is exactly right for your needs but should point you in the right direction:

```
Select-String 'Desktop/dict.txt' -pattern '^[bingo]{3,}$'
```